# Is it possible to create a JSON Schema with allOf (multiple if and then) and $ref?

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to create a complex schema that will check for the value of a property and then validate according to the value of that same property. I am wondering if it's possible to use $ref and allOf in the same schema and if so, how? I am having some trouble getting this to work. It may be important to note that I am using AJV. Please see my code below

```
{ 
  "$ref": "#/definitions/Welcome",
  "definitions": {
    "Welcome": {
      "properties": {
        "auth": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["oauth1","oauth2"]
        },
        "environment": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Environment"
        }
      }
    },
    "Environment": {
      "properties": {
        "dev": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    },
    "Oauth1": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "temporary_credentials": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "Oauth2": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "auth_url": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "auth": {
          "const": "oauth1"
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "environment": {
          "dev": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Oauth1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "auth": {
          "const": "oauth2"
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "environment": {
          "dev": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Oauth2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

A sample json input to be validated against **this** schema would be something like this

```
{
  "auth": "oauth1",
  "environment": {
    "dev": {
      "temporary_credentials": "xyzzy"
    }
  }
}
```

I feel like there might be an error in my "then" statements or simply the placement of the allOf. The error I would get is something like this "$ref: keywords ignored in schema at path "#"".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Schema if-else condition complex scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430680/json-schema-if-else-condition-complex-scenario)

Comment: @gregsdennis mine is using "if" and "then" with "$ref" thanks for your input though

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're using a `$ref` or an inline schema; the logic (and the solution) is the the same. Don't use `*Of` and `if`/`then`/`else` together.

Comment: Additionally, the schemas inside the `then` blocks need some `properties` callouts.

Comment: @gregsdennis why can't allOf and if/then/else be used together? I use it in my schemas; when I have a list of if/thens I wrap it in an allOf and never had problems with that.

Comment: They _can_ be used together, but they're not intended to be in the way that most people try it.  Read my answer on the duplicate suggestion (and the answer it links to).  Most people think of it iteratively, and it's not; it's declarative.

Answer (score 2):

In schema version up to and including draft7, once you use `"$ref"`, all other keywords in that level of the schema are ignored. That's what the error is telling you: because you used `$ref`, other keywords are ignored.

If you only want to use a `$ref` at the root level, the trick is to wrap it in an `"allOf"`.

But since you already have an `allOf` at the root level, you can just add the `$ref` as another branch of the `allOf` and it will work.

That would look like:

```
"allOf": [
{
  "$ref": "#/definitions/Welcome",
},
{
  "if": {
    "auth": {
      "const": "oauth1"
    }
    etc.
```

Note: in the schema you posted, you have two unclosed strings `"#/definitions/Oauth1` and `"#/definitions/Oauth2`. If you had that in your real schema it would be invalid JSON.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean when you say to "add the $ref as another branch of the allOf". If "allOf" is an array of objects, do you mean I should add "$ref" as an object to that array? Something like this ... "allOf": [ "$ref":{ }]. Quite new to this so sorry for being a bit slow

Comment: Ok, so the error went away now but the validator doesn't seem to be getting the schemas from the ref, hence not working. My schema is actually a bit different from the one I posted and more complicated. Is there any way I can contact you?

Comment: I was actually able to figure it out. Thanks for everything